# Data with special character when get data using InputStream data has been changed

Tags: java, utf-8, inputstreamreader

I have a web service which returns xml document contains characters like "ÅUðSÅU". When I read this file using 
`InputStreamReader`, it's generate string like "ÅUðâ??ÅU" .

I'm using `UTF-8` but not working. My code is following-

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
int value=0;                       
// reads to the end of the stream                  
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {              
      System.out.println("data--"+line);                          
      response += line;            
    }
```

Comment: You assume that the response is UTF-8 encoded - is this actually the case?

Comment: Most likely the encoding isn't the same.

Comment: BTW you are removing all the newlines when you read the input this way.

Comment: when running web service on browser window response shown <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">ÅUðSÅU</string>  but when i get code web service using HttpUrlConnection and get inputStream it's showing 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">ÅUðâ??ÅU </string>

Comment: @Smutje i have no idea response is UTF-8 encoded or not but when i remove UTF-8 then response is "Ã…UÃ°Ã¢ï¿½?Ã…U" and that is also not correct.  Peter How can i check encoding is same or not?

Comment: Yes, I thought so - either you keep experimenting with encodings or you check with the web service owner which encoding (he thinks) he is using and verify it.

Comment: @smutje i don't think it's webservice encoding issue i have also tried to get inputStream with contant data but same result- String txt="ÅUðSÅU" InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(txt.getBytes());
              BufferedReader br2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
              
                while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                
                
                                  System.out.println("data2--"+line);
                
                                    response += line;
                
                                }

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, when I run this code, I get `data2--ÅUðSÅU`.

Comment: have you seen above line of code now i'm not using webservice i just use string variable named "txt" which store special character then create inputStream object using "txt" and read the data from stream. but the result is "Ãƒâ€¦UÃƒÂ°SÃƒâ€¦U".

Comment: Yes, and as I see the correctly encoded text it has nothing to do with the text and presumable rather with your encoding settings.

Comment: You definitely have an encoding mismatch somewhere. You need to figure out where. Your web service is clearly not sending UTF-8 like you are expecting. What does the HTTP `Content-Type` header say the charset is being sent as?